# Cannot make a cache safe URL for "next/odspnext/en-us/splistreactcontrolsbeforeplt.resx.js", file not found

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, error, cache, internal-server-error

Sorry, something went wrong

Cannot make a cache safe URL for "next/odspnext/en-us/splistreactcontrolsbeforeplt.resx.js", file not found. Please verify that the file exists under the layouts directory.

[image: next odspnext en-us splistreactcontrolsbeforeplt resx js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have installed the related language package CU in your server, here is a similar issue for your reference:

https://www.reddit.com/r/sharepoint/comments/kx6maa/cache_safe_url/